# Proving that eigenvalues of real self adjoint endomorphism are real

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, symmetric-matrices, self-adjoint-operators

If $\mathbf{A}\colon V \to  V$ is selfadjoint for some finite dimensional vector space $V$
over $\mathbb{C}$ then this follows immediately, since for any nonzero eigenvalue
$\lambda $ and a corresponding eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$ we have
\begin{align*}
\lambda \left\langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{v}\right\rangle
= \left\langle \mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{v}\right\rangle 
= \left\langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}\right\rangle 
= \overline{\lambda }\left\langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{v}\right\rangle 
.\end{align*}
Can one argue in a similar way if $V$ is a vectorspace over $\mathbb{R}$?

I thought about
just considering the same vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ which, however, gives rise to several
questions: Is $\mathbf{A}$ again self adjoint over $\mathbb{C}$? Can we even extend
an inner product of $V$ w.r.t. to $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$?

For the latter question I would say yes, since (if we assumed we already have such an inner product
over $\mathbb{C}$)
\begin{align*}
\left\langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}\right\rangle _{\mathbb{C}}
&= \left\langle \mathbf{a} + i\mathbf{b}, 
\mathbf{c} + i\mathbf{d}\right\rangle _{\mathbb{C}}
\\
&= \left\langle \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{c}\right\rangle _{\mathbb{C}}
+ \left\langle \mathbf{a},i \mathbf{d}\right\rangle _{\mathbb{C}}
+ \left\langle i \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c}\right\rangle _{\mathbb{C}}
+ \left\langle i \mathbf{b}, i \mathbf{d}\right\rangle _{\mathbb{C}}
\\
&\stackrel{\text{(1)}}{=}  \left\langle \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{c}\right\rangle _{\mathbb{R}}
+i \left\langle \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{d} \right\rangle _{\mathbb{R}}
- i \left\langle \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c}\right\rangle _{\mathbb{R}}
+ \left\langle \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{d}\right\rangle _{\mathbb{R}}
\end{align*}
so we can simply use (1) as our definition (which turns out to satisfy all properties of a complex inner product). W.r.t. this inner product $\mathbf{A}$
would also be self adjoint again (so we can borrow the proof from above). Is this argumentation valid?

Comment: I'm a little confused. If $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$, then eigenvalues are automatically real by definition of eigenvalue, since complex scalars are not supported

Comment: The eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial over the algebraic closure of the base field; equivalently you can extend scalars to the algebraic closure and consider eigenvectors there.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan so do you think my approach is valid?

Comment: @Richard $T\in \mathcal{L}(V) $ , then $\lambda\in\color{red}{F}$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if $\exists v\in V\setminus\{0\}$ such that $Tv=\lambda v$ . So if $F=\Bbb{R}$ , then it follows from the definition that $\lambda\in \Bbb{R}$ ( whenever existence is confirmed).

Comment: @LostinSpace the definition in my textbook is exactly the one in the comments above (i.e. eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ in this case\)

Comment: @Richard Well. If $\chi_T(t) \in \Bbb{R}[t]$  , then zeros of $\chi_T$ over $\Bbb{R}$  are the eigen values.

Comment: @LostinSpace maybe I'm just expressing myself wrong but for the standard inner product my question could be phrased as: Show that all complex eigenvalues of a symmetric real matrix are real.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with another proof which is much more elementary than the attempted argumentation in my initial question:
Choosing some basis we know that $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{n, n} $
has some complex eigenvalue, let it be $\lambda $
with corresponding eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$, i.e. $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v} = \lambda \mathbf{v}$.
We can write $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}_{1} + i \mathbf{v}_{2}$ where $\mathbf{v}_{1}, \mathbf{v}_{2}
\in \mathbb{R}^{n} $ and $\lambda  = \lambda _{1} = i \lambda _{2}$ for
$\lambda _{1}, \lambda _{2} \in \mathbb{R}$. This yields the relations
\begin{align*}
  &\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}_{1} = \lambda _{1} \mathbf{v}_{1} - \lambda _{2} \mathbf{v}_{2}
\\[5pt] 
& \mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}_{2} = \lambda _{2} \mathbf{v}_{1} + \lambda _{1} \mathbf{v}_{2}
.\end{align*}
Now since $\mathbf{A}$ is self adjoint w.r.t. to the inner product that comes with
the real vectorspace $V$ we have $\left\langle \mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}_{1}, 
\mathbf{v}_{2}\right\rangle = \left\langle \mathbf{v}_{1}, \mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}_{2}\right\rangle $
giving us (plugging in the above relations
\begin{align*}
  &\left\langle \lambda _{1} \mathbf{v}_{1} - \lambda _{2} \mathbf{v}_{2}, 
\mathbf{v}_{2}\right\rangle  = 
\left\langle  \mathbf{v}_{1}, \lambda _{2} \mathbf{v}_{1} + \lambda _{1} \mathbf{v}_{2}\right\rangle 
\\
& \quad \iff  \lambda _{1}\left\langle \mathbf{v}_{1}, \mathbf{v}_{2} \right\rangle 
- \lambda _{2}\left\langle \mathbf{v}_{2}, \mathbf{v}_{2}\right\rangle 
= \lambda_{2}\left\langle \mathbf{v}_{1}, \mathbf{v}_{1}\right\rangle 
+ \lambda _{1}\left\langle \mathbf{v}_{2}, \mathbf{v}_{1}\right\rangle 
\\
& \quad \implies \lambda _{2}( \left\langle \mathbf{v}_{1}, \mathbf{v}_{1}\right\rangle 
+ \left\langle \mathbf{v}_{2}, \mathbf{v}_{2}\right\rangle ) = 0
.\end{align*}
Since $\mathbf{v}\neq 0$ by definition it follows that $\lambda _{2} = 0$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Evangelista Torricelli, an Italian physicist and mathematician, who was a student of Galileo and is known for his
invention of the barometer, once said

> Noi viviamo sommersi nel fondo d'un pelago d'aria. (We live submerged at the bottom of an ocean of air.)

The striking fact about this quotation it that, while it is obviously true, we don't usually feel that way.

Likewise, in mathematical terms, we live surrounded by complex numbers, although we often don't realize it, and this
post is perhaps another indication of this fact!

Nevertheless, let me try another answer which doesn't mention complex numbers at all.

**Theorem**.  Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator acting on a real Hilbert space $V$.  Then all of the roots of the
characteristic polynomial of $A$ are real.

*Proof*.  The proof will be by induction on the dimension of $V$.

- **Case 1:** $\text{dim}(V)=1$.

This is obvious!

- **Case 2:** $\text{dim}(V)=2$.

Let $M$ be the matrix of $A$ relative to an orthonormal basis, so $M$ is symmetric, and hence of the form
$$
  M=\pmatrix{a & b\cr b & c}.
  $$
The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is then
$$
  p(x) = (x-a)(x-c)-b^2 = $$$$ = x^2-(a+c)x+ac-b^2,
  $$
while its discriminant is
$$
  \Delta =(a+c)^2-4ac+4b^2 = $$ $$ =a^2+c^2-2ac+4b^2 = (a-c)^2+4b^2,
  $$
which is positive and hence the roots of $p$ are real.

- **Case 3:** $\text{dim}(V)\geq 3$.

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ has degree at least three, so it admits a real root, say $\lambda $.

Choose any
eigenvector $v$ associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda $, and let $W$ be the space orthogonal to $v$, namely
$$
  W=\{w\in V:\langle w, v\rangle =0\}.
  $$
I then claim that $A(W)\subseteq W$.  To see this, choose $w\in W$, and notice that
$$
  \langle Aw, v\rangle =
  \langle w, Av\rangle =
  \lambda \langle w, v\rangle = 0.
  $$
This proves the claim,  so we may restrict $A$ to $W$, obtaining an obviously self-adjoint operator $B:W\to W$.

Relative to the decomposition
$$
  V={\mathbb R}v\oplus W,
  $$
we then have that
$$
  A=\lambda 1\oplus B,
  $$
so it is easy to see
that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ coincides with
$$
  p(x)=(x-\lambda )g(x),
  $$
where $g$ is the characteristic polynomial
of $B$.

Since $\text{dim}(W)=\text{dim}(V)-1$, the induction hypothesis guarentees that all roots of $g$ are real and
so we are done!

Comment: Indeed a nice argument, follows the inductive spirit of the spectral theorem proof.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that does not involve changing the structure of the original vector space.

Let $M$ be the matrix of $A$ relative to any orthonormal basis of $V$.  Then $M$ is a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix over
${\mathbb R}$, where $n$ is the dimension of $V$.

Next we forget about $V$, and consider the linear transformation $B:{\mathbb C}^n\to {\mathbb C}^n$ given by the matrix
$M$ (this time viewed as a complex matrix).

Then $B$ is a self-adjoint complex-linear operator on ${\mathbb C}^n$, and the complex theory guarantees that
the roots of its characteristic polynomial coincide with the set of eigenvalues of $B$,  all of which are real.

Finally, we just have to notice that
the characteristic polynomial of $B$ is the same as that for $A$!

Comment: I'm only given that the $\mathbf{A}$ is self adjoint with respect to the inner product which comes with the vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$, so wouldn't your approach additionally require to show that $\mathbf{A}$ is also self adjoint w.r.t. the complex inner product?

Comment: If $A$ is self-adjoint on a real space, it's matrix $M$ is symmetric relative to any orthonormal basis, that is $M^t=M$.  Therefore, viewed as a complex matrix, $M$ coincides with its adjoint ($\bar M^t$ conjugate transpose) so it defines a self-adjoint operator on $\mathbb C^n$.

Comment: I agree, it's straight forward to see that $M$ must be symmetric to be self adjoint over a real finite inner product space and hermitian for a complex f.i.p. space. I don't exactly know what you mean with "the complex theory", but given these results, you can just borrow the proof from the very beginning of my question. I think my initial desire was to obtain a proof that doesn't rely on the fact that the respective matrices are symmetric/hermetian but only use a small set of rules of an inner product.

Comment: @Richard.  Yes, by "complex theory" I mean precisely the results you mention for the complex case.

Comment: @Richard. *"I think my initial desire was to obtain a proof that doesn't rely on the fact that the respective matrices are symmetric/hermetian ..."*.  Please let me know how do you like my other answer.

Comment: I mean it's certainly a nice answer, but my initial question was whether the proof I proposed is correct.

Comment: I don't think your method works.  The trouble is that you cannot make a real vector space into a complex one in any natural way.   For example, if the real dimension of $V$ is odd, there is no way to make it a complex vector space that somewhat preserves the real structure.

Comment: But actually I just show that given our real inner product we can extend this to a complex inner product. Now, with respect to this complex inner product our endomorphism is still self adjoint and hence one can borrow the proof from the complex case. Could you point out my mistake in this argument?

Comment: "*I thought about just considering the same vector space over ${\mathbb C}$.*"  I don't think there is a way to do that.  How
would you define the multiplication $\lambda v$, when $\lambda $ is the imaginary unit?

Comment: I would define it as $\lambda v = (a + bi) v = va + bi v$

Comment: actually to make this construction rigorous one way would be to consider $V \otimes _{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$. Incidentally my course currently covers this so it might be a nice application. At some point I will write it down and post it here as an answer.